# Segmentation fault with Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to use Rails 3.2.0.rc2 but I'm running into some problems. When I try to do a `rails s` I am now getting:

```
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/json-1.6.5/ext/json/ext/json/ext/parser.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]

[1]    28744 abort      rails s
```

What's interesting is that I am using 1.9.2 but the error seems to be related to 1.8.7. I have done the following to try to fix this problem w/ no success:

```
rvm gemset empty
rvm use 1.9.2@skateparks
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

Comment: Segmentation fault in a scripting language is bug. File a bug.

Comment: For what it's worth: Rails 4.0 (the next major release of Rails after 3.2) will drop support for Ruby 1.8.7, so it would be wise to do the same if you plan on using edge rails.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could try rebuilding some or all of your gems. It may be related to your shared libraries and `.bundle` files.

JSON has a compiled extension that might've been corrupted or rendered incompatible.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: `gem install json` for instance. You can also rebuild all gems if you like with `gem pristine --all`